# Java port of Hash by Jenkins

Tags: java, hash

I am looking for a java port of this file, 
[Jenkins Hash in C](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/c/lookup2.c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://256stuff.com/sources/jenkins_hash_java/) looks like one.

Though, by the looks of description on the Wikipedia article you could port it yourself without too much trouble.

Answer (score 1):

[Hsieh's hash](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/hash.html) is even better. I don't know of a java implementation - i'm writing one right now.

Comment: Crumbs, that took a while: http://urchin.earth.li/~twic/Code/HsiehHash.java

Comment: Could be me, but that code looks buggy. E.g. the first line in the for-loop takes the hashCode of `things` instead of `thing`.

Comment: Yup, looks like complete nonsense to me too. When someone posts code, always demand to see the unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

At Github there is [g414-hash](https://github.com/sunnygleason/g414-hash) project which includes hash functions you might want to use, including jenkins, murmur, hsieh and cwow. It also has bloom filter implementation for which hashes can be used.

Answer (score 1):

A duck duck go searched reveals this: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/JenkinsHash.htm

Answer (score 0):

Apache licensed - http://people.apache.org/~yonik/code/hash/Hash.html